# adding a popup file browser to a QtVariantPropertyManager

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a field in a property browser where the user sets a file path.  I would like for them to get a file browser when the click on the line to edit it.
the file browser is

```
class TargetPropertiesBrowser(QtTreePropertyBrowser):
    def __init__(self):
        self._variantManager = QtVariantPropertyManager()

        general_group = self._variantManager.addProperty(QtVariantPropertyManager.groupTypeId(), "General")

        self._outputPath = self._variantManager.addProperty(QVariant.String, Target.OUTPUT_PATH)
        self._outputPath.setToolTip("Output Directory")
        general_group.addSubProperty(self._outputPath)
```

Now lets say I have some class PopUpBrowser that defines the popup I want displayed when they click in the property browser on the file path line.  I can't find an example or documentation on how to alter the behavior or the QtTreePropertyBrowser.

Edit:
If there is a signal I can connect to for when a user clicks on the line that would be fine, however I don't see such a signal in the docs.  I'm also not seeing any Enum for a variant manager (or any alternate managers) that supports a widget or button that could link a widget.  Sorry if I was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Connect one of the Widget's Signals (e.g. clicked()) to a slot method in your class: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html

Comment: I understand signals and slots, but how do I connect that to a specific entry in the tree property browser?

Comment: @James I have only worked with [QtTreePropertyBrowser](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtpropertybrowser) in C++ a while ago. Documentation seems scarce. You will have to follow the Widgets and their input events/Signals and then connect or reimplement handlers where lacking. Sorry I cannot be more specific.